# Compiling python for ubuntu linux, cx_python

Tags: python, linux, compilation, bytecode

I need to be able to distribute my python script, preferably in linux byte code.
It has several dependencies that are located in directories as such:

```
extensions
    python  >> run.py
    python  >> protocols.py
    plugins >> Folder contains more run.py dependencies
    bash    >> Contains bash scripts needed
```

I've tried simply cd-ing to extensions/python and running cxfreeze run.py.
However, this creates several files in a dist folder, none of which (including
'run' are executable. There are no 'make' instructions created in this directory.

How would I do this? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the Python 2.6+ feature of executing zip files. See an [elaborate blog article](http://sayspy.blogspot.de/2010/03/various-ways-of-distributing-python.html); in short:

1. create .pyc files for all your modules, e.g. by importing them once
2. write an `__main__.py`
3. zip up the `__main__.py`, and all .pyc files, e.g. as foo.zip
4. test, using `python foo.zip`
5. prepend a line `#!/usr/bin/python` to the zip file (e.g. with echo and cat)
6. set the x bit on the resulting file